# close div should not show after reload

Tags: jquery

This my script it's working fine

```
$(".close-notification").click(function () {
  $(".page-header").removeClass("notify-me");
  $(".top-notification_pannel").hide();
  });
```

but my problem is after reload it show again I want to show only cache expired or session expired only

Comment: You need to use something like localStorage

Comment: Yes correct......